# Permaculture and World Food Needs

Tags: permaculture, sustainability

Can permaculture techniques feed the world's nutrition requirements? Are we stuck with GM crops to feed the worlds burgeoning population?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about large scale agriculture. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: I know this is closed, but have to say this - we might be stuck with GM crops because someone's making money out of them, but poverty is the cause of malnutrition and hunger, and poverty is directly related to greed for money and land. There is plenty of food to go round, it just doesn't get to those without money and land rights. So that's why we'll end up with GM foods...http://www.globalissues.org/article/7/causes-of-hunger-are-related-to-poverty

Comment: Humans have also made GM crops since we discovered genetics, so the only way to avoid this is to find the plant in the wild, which would be very hard to do.